# How often is too often to bathe a dog?

Tags: dogs, grooming, bathing

I have a pug/Chihuahua/Pomeranian mix that we bathe once a week. Is this too often? I find that if we leave her without a bath for more then a week and a half she starts to develop a faint smell (nothing overwhelming).

I heard it can be harmful to a dogs coat if you bathe them too often and I am worried that we are doing her more harm than good.

Comment: Just an example of the opposite: We never bathe our dogs. In summer they swim in a lake and in winter they run in deep snow. During spring or fall they sometimes gather a smell, but nothing too bad and a good brushing takes care of that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**General Rule:** Whatever the breed is, it is advisable not to bathe your dog more than once a month unless otherwise instructed by a vet using proper shampoo and soap.

If you bathe a dog too often, its coat will lose shine and the dog can become itchy. Also, dog has a natural coat protecting system which can get harmed by over-bathing. So, once a month is preferable.

However, we bathe our German Shepherd twice a month and I haven't experienced anything problematic about it.

As far as the smell goes, it is very natural for a dog to have some smell. It should not bother you.

Comment: Can you point to some research that supports this answer?

Comment: @chris, Mostly I read these stuffs from some periodicals.

Comment: @Mistu4u can you point to one such periodical?

Answer (score 9):

It is natural for a dog to have a light smell, I wouldn't bathe a dog unless it got dirty. Most dirt can simply be rubbed off the fur by using a dry towel, which I would prefer to bathing.

Dogs are waterproof, so as long as you are not using soap there isn't much to worry about. Our Labradors used to jump into every water source available, no matter how cold or smelly.
If you need to use soap, be sure to use a soap that is approved to be used on dogs. There are special soaps available in most pet stores or online that don't affect the protective layers on the skin too much.

Comment: just as a note: having a dog jump into water regularly might lead to problems (like fungal infections in the ear).

Comment: Just a note all animals are waterproof. perhaps you could elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I rescued a Pomeranian, they had shaved his hair two days before and had flees.  My other dog a maltipoo, I had bathed him for a year every week; so I started bathing the Pomeranian too. I did not know that they had so much hair problems at all. I only read about the maltipoo. Anyway the Pomeranian came home at 1 and a half years, and in very bad hair condition. He was always tired and looked sad. After a month 4 baths at home and all the brushing; just as the maltipoo.  He stoped scratching, no flees and his hair is soooo pretty now; very happy too. I felt it changed his whole personality the maltipoo was always jumping and playing with toys. Now they both play and are very active and happy. I took my Pomeranian to the park today and someone asked where I have him groomed, because they need someone that leaves the hair like mine. I have not taken him anywhere that is why we I started reading about them. I do not even know if I want to stop bathing him so much, I feel it really helps him.